# How to distribute padding equally among

Tags: css, position

I've got three images side by side.. equal width..
 
How to percentage the padding-left property to fits multiple devices?
by percentage of padding-lefts, I don't want the images to be right beside themselves.. want to distribute them among the available screen width evenly

```
img { padding-left: some% }
```

considering the equal width of images.. if the padding-left is to much it pushes the 3rd image to the next row with some devices

Comment: you can make the img width and height also in %

Comment: @AspiringAqib and then distribute the paddings with the remaining percentage: widths: 30% 30% 30% and paddings: 3% 3% 3% ?

Comment: @AspiringAqib  I see that probably would work.. but I'm hard coding the image sizes and would really prefer not to use % with the image sizes. Is there a way to just % the paddings?

Comment: well buddy, if can you use a little jQuery or JS? because images will become wierd when use %.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This pure CSS2 solution](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/G4BrY/2/) does the job:

Markup:

```
<div id="images">
  <div>
    <img src="" alt="" /><img src="" alt="" /><img src="" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Style sheet (provided [images e.g. 100px wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307107/how-to-distribute-padding-equally-among/14308611#comment19876187_14307107)):

```
#images {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#images div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 -50px;
  font-size: 0;
}
#images img {
  position: relative;
  left: 25%;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
#images img + img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
#images img + img + img {
  left: 75%;
}
```

Explanation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries in your CSS to target specific screen widths and then use the padding-left % to compensate for different screens for e.g

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { }
```

This will only target screens with a maximum width of 480px

Answer (score 0):

Without requiring extra markup, Flexbox will do what you need *and* it is automatically flexible.  The down side is that it isn't widely supported yet.

http://jsfiddle.net/hv3Gk/ (prefixes not included, try Opera)

```
div.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: row wrap; /* or nowrap if you know its guaranteed to fit no matter what */
}

div.container img {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

Otherwise, you could use the `display: table` properties, but it requires extra markup.  It will work in IE8+ and just about any other browser version released in the last 5 years.

http://jsfiddle.net/hv3Gk/1/

```
div.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

div.container div {
  display: table-cell;
}

div.container div:first-child + div {
  text-align: center;
}

div.container div:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}

div.container img {
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```